# Let $f: [a, +\infty [\to \mathbb{R}$ derivable such that $\lim_{x\to+\infty} xf'(x) = k> 0$. Prove that $\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x)=+ \infty$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: [a, +\infty [\to \mathbb{R}$ derivable such that $\lim_{x\to+\infty} xf'(x) = k> 0$. Prove that $\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x)=+ \infty$.

If is not the case, then: there exists $M>0$ and an increasing sequence $(x_n)_n$ of the elements of $[a,+\infty[$ such that $f(x_n)<M$, for all $n$. I thought about using Mean value theorem and Roll's Theorem, but I can't use them, There is an easy method?

Comment: When you say you "can't" use MVT and/or Rolle's Theorem, do you mean you tried and couldn't find a way to do so, or do you mean you're not permitted to do so (because, for example, you haven't covered them in your course yet)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another approach but using mean value instead of integration.

Notice $\Big(f(e^x)\Big)'=e^xf'(e^x)\to k>0$ at infinity.

Similarly $\forall x>x_0$ then $\Big(f(e^x)\Big)'>\frac k2$ and by MVT $f(e^x)-f(e^{x_0})=f'(e^\xi)(x-x_0)$

Therefore $f(e^x)>f(e^{x_0})+\frac k2(x-x_0)$ which admitedly is almost word for word what's obtained by user284331 in his answer.

Comment: This is very clever.

Answer (score 4):

Find an $M>0$ such that $xf'(x)>k/2$ for all $x\geq M$, then
\begin{align*}
f(x)=f(M)+\int_{M}^{x}f'(t)dt\geq f(M)+\dfrac{k}{2}\int_{M}^{x}\dfrac{1}{t}dt=f(M)+\dfrac{k}{2}(\log x-\log M)\rightarrow\infty
\end{align*}
as $x\rightarrow\infty$.

**EDIT:**

Look at @zwim answer for the case that $f'$ is not integrable.

Comment: is a derivative function always integrable on a compact?

Comment: But why is $ f'$ continuous on any compact interval?

Comment: @saidnani Good point, [no, not necessarily](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6711/integrability-of-derivatives).